# Issue with database connection in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, database

I got a login issue in trying to connect to a SQL Server database.

I can enter the SQL Server Management Studio with `sa` account with right password, but when I try to connect to SQL Server database from Visual Studio, the error message ("login failed with sa account") shows up and I can't connect to the SQL Server database.

I can see error logs (error code 18456,  wrong password) in SQL Server Management Studio, when I execute `sp_readerrorlog`.

When I try to connect to the SQL Server database in Visual Studio with Windows authentication, it seems connection to the database is working.

I don't know what is the problem when I try to connect to the SQL Server database even though I know `sa` account with right password.

Many threads say this problem is about SERVER PROPERTIES-> SECURITY -> SET SERVER AUTHENTICATION TO THE SQL SERVER AND WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION MODE in Management Studio, but I already confirmed it.

Comment: what is your connection string?

Comment: sorry I didn't check your reply because this is my first time using this site and I am beginner in development. 

I used connectionstring when I practiced asp.net mvc web development but I'm following windows forms tutorial in this site

Comment: (http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~thicks/Tutorials/Visual-Studio-Windows-App-Form-MSSQL-Connection-ComboBox/Visual-Studio-Windows-App-Form-MSSQL-Connection-ComboBox.html)
and in this part I'm trying to add some data from database to the form. In this tutorial, there was no connection string use. just connect to the database that has been already created from the window form, and add some data from the database to the form.

Comment: but I can't even start connecting to the database with sa account. I wrote above window authentication working but I confirmed it's not too. I think this is a problem about connection setting between visual studio and mssql

Comment: Actually I kind of hope your DBA disabled the sa account which would make connecting impossible. It's a bad practice to expose the sa account.  Have you verified this?

Comment: oh how can I verify if my dba made my sa account disabled?
I can enter to the mssql management studio with sa account with password but that doesn't mean my dba made my sa account enabled?

Comment: And I just found something strange.
I can change the password of sa account like password : 1234 in window authentication mode in mssql management studio, and I could login and enter to the mssql management studio with sa account with password 1234 for the first time login try, and after a few minutes later , maybe, when I try to login with sa account with same password 1234 for the second time. I can't login and enter to the mssql management studio with sa account with password 1234

Comment: and I wrote a additional post with additional information about this issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490913/login-failure-issue-with-sa-account-in-visual-studio

Comment: Please don't post duplicates. Please just edit your existing question with any information

Comment: It seems you have confirmed via SSMS that the sa account is being automatically reset somehow. Or so it would seem. Is this your SQL Server or are you using someone elses?

Comment: Ok I will follow it thx for noticing it. I'm using my sql server at home.

Comment: problem seems like resolved. I searched autorecovery in SSMS and tried some settings but still not working and then I could see a login failure log in SSMS representing the message like Staring up database 'a cerain database file' which message I overlooked and login failed message followed after it. so I deleted that database file in SSMS and it seems like sa account is working. Connection done once well.

Comment: that was probably not the cause, still not working